# Create test account using Facebook API returns response with incorrect email format

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I faced with the problem while creating new user test account through API, that the email format in the response is not correct.

here is my response:

{
   "id": "xxxx",
   "access_token": "xxxx",
   "login_url": "xxxx",
   "email": "qapuvvl_schrockstein_1354772402\u0040tfbnw.net",
   "password": "xxxx"
}

so it changes "@" sign to backslash.

any suggestion why it happens?

Thanks.
Aleksey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The email id for the test users on facebook is of the domain `tfbnw.net` so it is not changing "@" to backslash but the JSON returned contains the Unicode form of "@" symbol.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters

You can change it back while you are deserializing the JSON array.